# Changing observation from ID to ID-year pair

Tags: stata

I have this data

```
ID    A1  A2 B1 B2  C
1     0   1  2   3  4
2     5   6  7   8  9
```

Here, A1 means A at year 1, A2 means A at year 2. Same goes for B.

I want to make a data where each row is ID-year pair, not just ID.

Like this:

```
ID  year  A  B  C
 1   1    0  2  4
 1   2    1  3  4
 2   1    5  7  9
 2   2    6  8  9
```

Luckily, there are same number of years of A and B.

Honestly I am stuck and all I could come up was just create the desired data structure first and manually copy and paste things. But the data is too big to do it manually.

How should I go about it?

EDIT:

The names of the variables should be more like below:

```
ID    A00  A01 B00 B01  C
1     0   1  2   3  4
2     5   6  7   8  9
```

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. The effect was to render my answer incorrect and harder to follow. It's fine to revise your question, but not so fine to muddy the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See help for the `reshape` command. It's a `reshape long` problem.

```
clear 
input ID    A1  A2 B1 B2  C
1     0   1  2   3  4
2     5   6  7   8  9
end 

reshape long A B , i(ID) j(Year) 

list, sepby(ID) 

     +-----------------------+
     | ID   Year   A   B   C |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |  1      1   0   2   4 |
  2. |  1      2   1   3   4 |
     |-----------------------|
  3. |  2      1   5   7   9 |
  4. |  2      2   6   8   9 |
     +-----------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Thank you! But it seems the actual problem was that the year indicator actually looked like "00" "01" indicating 2000 and 2001. In this case, Stata seems to think A00, A01, B00, B01 are actually just like "C" which is constant across years. I revised the variable name in my question to clarify this. How do I fix it?

Comment: The effect of your revision (marked by an EDIT to your question) is just that stubs need to be changed. Command is now  `reshape long A0 B0 , i(ID) j(Year)`